# Extend numpy array based on tags

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have

```
a1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
a2 = np.array(list('abcd'))
b2 = np.array(list('aabcccdd'))
```

How do I get to b1 which should be

```
array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4])
```

EDIT: In other words, `a1` values correspond to `a2` 'tags' and I want to generate the values corresponding to `b2`.

Comment: I think people would easily get confused with a sample which has `b2` simply extended "double" for each element. Or do you actually have such a simplistic one as the actual case?

Comment: No, you are right. I will edit it to be clearer

Comment: Just, use a bit more representative sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `a2` to be sorted, here's one using [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
a1[np.searchsorted(a2,b2)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [145]: a1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
     ...: a2 = np.array(list('abcd'))
     ...: b2 = np.array(list('aabbccdd'))
     ...: 

In [146]: a1[np.searchsorted(a2,b2)]
Out[146]: array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4])
```

For the generic case when `a2` is not sorted, we need to bring in `sorter` argument -

```
In [148]: np.random.shuffle(a2)

In [149]: a2
Out[149]: 
array(['b', 'd', 'c', 'a'], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [152]: sidx = a2.argsort()

In [155]: a1[sidx[np.searchsorted(a2,b2, sorter=sidx)]]
Out[155]: array([4, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpys built-in functions `numpy.repeat` and `numpy.tile` are excellent for this kind of job.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array((1, 2, 3, 4))
print(arr)
[1, 2, 3, 4]

print(numpy.repeat(arr, 2))
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]

print(numpy.tile(arr, 2))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: So, you actually don't need `a2` or `b2`? :)

Comment: If you just want to repeat any given array, I'd say no.

Comment: Thanks for the response but that was not what I was after. Please see my edited OP. I erroneously thought it would be obvious. Divakar's solution works just fine.

Comment: Sure, no problem - I thought, you just wanted this specific array.